# Can this problem be modelled with a transformation from a known TSP with profits?

Tags: modeling, combinatorial-optimization, traveling-salesman

The **profitable tour problem** (PTP) is defined on a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$, where each vertex $i \in V$ has an associated prize $m_i \geq 0$ and each edge $e \in E$ has an associated cost $c_e \geq 0$.
The problem asks to find a subset of vertices and a tour visiting them, maximising the difference between prizes collected and travel costs paid.
Let $\mathbf{y} \in \{0,1\}^n$ be a vector whose $i$-th entry is 1 iff vertex $i \in V$ is included in the tour, and let $\text{TSP}(\mathbf{y})$ denote the cost of the shortest tour over the vertices included by $\mathbf{y}$.
Furthermore denote the vector of profits as $\mathbf{m} = (m_1, \ldots, m_n)$.
Then one can write the PTP as:

$$ \max_{\mathbf{y} \in \{0,1\}^n} \big\{ \mathbf{m}^\intercal \mathbf{y} - \text{TSP}(\mathbf{y}) \big\}$$

I have a problem which is, in some informal sense, *dual* to the PTP.
My problem can be written as follows:

$$ \max_{\mathbf{y} \in \{0,1\}^n} \big\{ \text{TSP}(\mathbf{y}) - \mathbf{m}^\intercal \mathbf{y} \big\}$$

In other words, I am looking for a subset of vertices of $V$ over which the shortest tour is longest but, to include a vertex $i$ in my tour, I have to pay a penalty $m_i$.

I have been thinking about it for a while, but I feel like the opposite optimisation direction between the outer maximisation problem and the inner minimisation (hidden in $\text{TSP}$) makes it hard to tackle this problem simply with a transformation from an existing [TSP with profits](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/3067/136), such as the PTP.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a straightforward transformation to a well-known problem that I don't see?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a real life problem ?

Comment: @Kuifje in some sense... solving it would give a bound on a real-life problem.

Comment: I need some time to think about it, but have you thought of transformation from a known TSP by setting the costs $c_{ij}$ to $-c_{ij}$  (in order to have a min TSP problem)?

Comment: Initially I thought about that, but I discarded the idea because I thought it was bound to find *longest* tours in the inner TSP problem, not shortest. I might be wrong, though... I will think more about it.

Comment: There is literature on the MAX TSP ... i mean the "taxicab rip off problem" (see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227191741_The_Maximum_TSP)

Comment: @user3680510: exactly. I think swapping the sign on edge costs as proposed by Kuifje would lead me to a MaxTSP, which is not what I am trying to solve. I might be missing something in Kuifje's reasoning, though.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini Nope this was my (possibly bad) idea indeed ! But are you 100% sur that a MaxTSP isn't what you're looking for ? Is it because of the penalties ?

Comment: If it is a directed graph you can just add the m values to all incoming edges.

Comment: Something is unclear to me. Do you have some sort of TSP solver and would like to use it to solve your problem ? Or are you trying to show a reduction from one problem to another for complexity theory ?

Comment: So, I would say it's not a MaxTSP because you still want to find the **shortest** tour over the vertices that you visit, not the *longest* one. Second, I would like to explore reductions to the TSP to, e.g., use Concorde to solve this problem or, otherwise, to make sure I don't start working on it just to realise at the end that a simple transformation would have turned it into an already well-known problem. For example, if it turns out to be a PTP then you can use well-known transformations PTP -> ATSP and then ATSP -> TSP and give it to Concorde.

Comment: I understand the confusion might have arisen from me using the "longest TSP" terminology. I didn't mean that the problem asks for the longest hamiltonian tour. I edited the question and I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So in a way it is a $\max \min $ TSP right ? There are some articles for the $\min \max $ TSP, for example here :
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03005493 . But still quite not your problem.

Comment: @Kuifje Correct. From a cursory look to the min max TSP paper I also agree that it doesn't look much like this problem. Maybe it is, in the end, novel and not easy to transform into a known problem.

Comment: Maybe you could try on mathoverflow if nobody is inspired here. But if nobody has answered, probably, to answer your question: no, you are not missing something obvious! Sounds tricky